# How do i fix my Problem in Unity Shader Graph 2018.2 for my Mac OS

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shader

[image]

Those spheres are missing from that transparent place. Can't Modify anything. Also there's some Metal shader warnings. I've already installed shader graph, lightweight render pipeline. Spent hours && hours. what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The warning error is from the metal editor, so just try to disable in edit->projectsetting->player->othersetting and untick the metal editor support.